# displaying large diagram

Tags: landscape, commutative-diagrams

I am trying to manage a big commutative diagram. First, I resized trough the routine

```
\resizebox{0.55\width}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzcd}...
        \end{tikzcd}
```

With this, the diagram is not readable because to small.

So, I took a screen-shot of the diagram

[image]

and I used

```
$$
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{big_diagram.png}
        \label{fig:LandscapeFigure}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
$$
```

But the diagram is still not readable. How can I mangage this ?

Comment: I'd probably try redesigning the diagram so it takes up less space. Perhaps introducing line breaks in some of the longer expressions, and reducing some of the horizontal spacing. A few other things though: By `\width`, do you mean `\textwidth`? If yes, why not `\textwidth` instead of `0.55\textwidth`? Further, why the screenshot route? You can put the `tikzcd` environment directly into the `sidewaysfigure`. Finally, the `$$ .. $$` around the `sidewaysfigure` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: It is very helpful to include a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. It saves other users a lot of time if they can just copy your code and work with it.

Answer (score 4):

Three suggestions:

First, the arrows in rows 4 and 6 are unnecessarily long. This is because the entry in row 7, column 3 is very wide and `tikz-cd` won't overlap the columns. You can override this with an `\llap` command in that entry.

[image]

Note that you should only `\llap` *most* of that entry, not the whole thing so that the arrow from above still points to a portion of the entry.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
AAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[rrr,equal]\arrow[dd] &&& AAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,"s"]\\
&&& AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,"P"]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d] &&& AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & I_1\arrow[r] & I_2\arrow[r,"\simeq"]\arrow[dd]& AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[dd,equal]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[rr] && I_3\arrow[d] & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d]\\
&& \llap{$BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB$}CCCC\arrow[r,equal] & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,"f"]\\
&&& AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\end{tikzcd}
```

Second, if you don't mind reorganizing a bit, you could save some more space by removing a column and have your map from `I_1` to `I_2` be vertical.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzcd}
AAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[rr,equal]\arrow[d] && AAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,"s"]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d] && AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,"P"]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & I_1\arrow[d] & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d] & I_2\arrow[r,"\simeq"]\arrow[d]& AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,equal]\\
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[r] & I_3\arrow[d] & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d]\\
& \llap{$BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB$}CCCC\arrow[r,equal] & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\arrow[d,"f"]\\
&& AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\end{tikzcd}
```

Third, if you still need a bit more space, you have a repeated expression `\mu hom(G_1,G_2)` in many entries. You could assign that expression to a single character. For example, `Let $\mathcal{M}=\mu hom(G_1,G_2)$.` Then substitute `\mathcal{M}` in your diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You can save much space by splitting the biggest object across two lines using `aligned` and using a bent arrow that avoids repeating another big object.

In `aligned` one needs the `\amp` trick because inside `tikzcd` the symbol `&` has another meaning.

Look in the manual for how to fill in the circled letters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{rotating}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mhom}{\mu hom}
\newcommand{\uR}{\mathrm{R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}

\centering\footnotesize
\let\amp=& % for the inner aligned

\begin{tikzcd}
\uR p^{}_{1_!} p^{-1}_{2^a} \mhom(G_1,G_2) \arrow[rrr,equals] \arrow[dd] 
%&&[-11em]&[-3em]
&&&
\uR p^{}_{1_!} p^{-1}_{2^a} \mhom(G_1,G_2) \arrow[d,"s"]
\\
&&&
\uR p^{}_{1_!}(K_W\otimes p^{-1}_{2^a} \mhom(G_1,G_2)) \arrow[d,"P"]
\\
\uR p^{}_{1_!}(K_W\otimes p^{-1}_{2^a} \mhom(G_1,G_2)) \arrow[d] &&&
\uR p^{}_{1_!}(p^{-1}_1 E_U\otimes K_W\otimes p^{-1}_{2^a} \mhom(G_1,G_2)) \arrow[d]
\\
\uR p^{}_{1_!}(\mhom(L,\Omega_{X\times Y/X}\otimes p^{-1}_{2^a}\mhom(G_1,G_2))
  \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &
\mathscr{I}_1 \arrow[r] &
\mathscr{I}_2 \arrow[r,"\simeq"] \arrow[dd] &
\begin{aligned}[t]
\amp\uR p^{}_{1_!}(\uR p^{}_{12_!}(p^{-1}_{12}\mhom(\CC_{\Delta_X},\Omega_{X\times X/X})[d_X] \\
\amp\qquad  \otimes p^{-1}_{2^a3}\mhom(L,\Omega_{X\times Y/X})
  \otimes p^{-1}_{3^a}\mhom(G_1,G_2))) \arrow[dd,equals]
\end{aligned}
\\
\mhom(L\circ G_1,\Omega_{X\times Y/X}\circ G_2) \arrow[d]
\\
\uR\tilde{p}^{}_{1_!}(\delta^a_* E_U 
  \otimes \tilde{p}^{-1}_{2^a}\mhom(L\circ G_1,\Omega_{X\times Y/X}\circ G_2))
  \arrow[rr] &&
\mathscr{I}_3 \arrow[dr,to path=|-(\tikztotarget.real west)] &
\mhom(\CC_{\Delta_X},\Omega_{X\times X/X})[d_X]\circ
  \mhom(L,\Omega_{X\times Y/X})\circ\mhom(G_1,G_2) \arrow[d] \\
&&&
\mhom(\CC_{\Delta_X}\circ L\circ G_1,\Omega_{X\times X/X}\circ\Omega_{X\times Y/X}\circ G_2)[d_X]
  \arrow[d,"\int"]
\\
&&&
\mhom(L\circ G_1,\Omega_{X\times Y/X}\circ G_2)
\end{tikzcd}

\caption{A very big diagram}

\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]